# Sympy expression-generating functions spending all their time in __mul__; how to speed up?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to help a colleague who's writing code which traverses a graph and makes a Very Large polynomial composed of sin/cos terms, and the bulk of the time is spent just multiplying these terms together (nothing special, code like x = y*z and x *= y, where x and y reference sympy variables).

What I found after profiling is that almost all the time spent (80-90%) is not in his code at all, but rather in SymPy's `decorator.py` and all the way down; see the SnakeViz visualization of the code below his call at the bottom.  It seems to spend much of its time just creating new Mul objects, and no small part of that time flattening them.

What I can't figure out is how to speed this up; there's not that much time spent *in* his code.  I tried being clever and thinking I could write a polynomial-specific library to take advantage of hashing, but SymPy was still faster.  Still... any ways to speed this up?  Increase caching? Turn off flattening?  Some sort of precedence we should be watching for?  I'm baffled.  It could be at the end of the day we just can't do this, but I feel like we're missing something obvious.

[image: snakeviz of profiling]

Answer (score 0):

`sympy` is a complex package built on top of python.  Intuitions that we develop about speed for python or `numpy` (array) operations don't apply.

In an `isympy` session, it `x` is a `sympy.Symbol`:

```
In [75]: x
Out[75]: x

In [76]: xx = 2*x

In [77]: type(xx)
Out[77]: sympy.core.mul.Mul
```

`multiplication` creates a `Mul` object, which is a subclass of `sympy.Expr` etc.

It's only when we substitute a number for the symbol does it perform conventional multiplication:

```
In [78]: xx.evalf(subs={x:23})
Out[78]: 46.0000000000000
```

Most of the `sympy` operations just create new expressions.  For example:

```
In [99]: xx = x*(y+z)

In [100]: xx
Out[100]: x⋅(y + z)       # a Mul object 

In [101]: expand(_)
Out[101]: x⋅y + x⋅z       # now an Add object is the outer most

In [102]: simplify(_)
Out[102]: x⋅(y + z)       # back to the Mul version
```